# Second expansion and substitution on makefile targets

Tags: makefile, expansion

I am trying to do second expansion in a makefile with substitution.
A sample makefile:

```
# We have src{0..3}.md documents. Generate them with
#
#   for i in src{0..3}.md; do echo "Hello in $i" > $i; done
#
# doc0.txt and doc2.txt are capitalized and doc1.txt and doc3b.txt are
# lowercased.

CAP_DOCS := doc0.txt doc2.txt
LOW_DOCS := doc1.txt doc3.txt
DOCS := $(CAP_DOCS) $(LOW_DOCS)

all: $(DOCS)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(CAP_DOCS): $$(@:doc%.txt=src%.md)
    tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' < $< > $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(LOW_DOCS): $$(@:doc%.txt=src%.md)
    tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' < $< > $@
```

And the error I get is

```
$ make 
Makefile:15: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.
```

I also tried setting `perc=%` and replacing the `%` characters with `$(perc)` and even `$$(perc)` as I figured it was trying to expand them before the second expansion and failed. It didn't help.

Comment: You only need `.SECONDEXPANSION` once. It applies to all rules defined after it.

Comment: [unrelated] wow, that sucks. Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. And yes, that's the main reason I avoid it. I don't like the world-changing nature of its behaviour.

Comment: Read the GNU `make` manual on [Secondary expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion).  When was the last time you wrote a dependency line with `$$` notation and didn't want secondary expansion?  System V `make` did it automatically (and it was very useful on occasion).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My point was more that I dislike world-changing flags when they don't need to be world-changing and that I so rarely need secondary expansion as to make it not worth generally dealing with. (Also the "after the definition" bit is just slightly awkward for a world-changing flag.)

Comment: use `$(CAP_DOCS): $(CAP_DOCS:doc%.txt=src%.md)` instead. you don't need .SECONDEXPANSION

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also couldn't get hiding the `%` from make with variables to work though that was also my first thought.

I was able to get `$(CAP_DOCS): $$(patsubst doc%.txt,src%.md,$$@)` and `$(LOW_DOCS): $$(patsubst doc%.txt,src%.md,$$@` working though.

I haven't tried it, but I wonder if you could just hide the substitution ref in a define or something and achieve the same effect.

Comment: Didn't try it on the test makefile but it did work on the original. Thank you